# How can I prevent button overflow on header when using vertical scrollbar in Visualforce page?

Tags: scrollbar, overlap, visualforce

I am using following Visualforce Code  where I am using a Page Block inside a Output Panel

( code given below )

Here I need to place a Vertical Scroll Bar and followed following Link which worked for me

(<apex:outputPanel styleClass="scrollable">)

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148322/scrolling-in-pageblocktable

But the Problem I am facing is button overflows on Header when Vertical scroll bar is used

Can you please help me to fix this issue ?

Regards

Deb

[Error Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVmxN.png)

```
                       <apex:pageBlock mode="edit" id="tableformblockIdSmAllExpA"  rendered="{!IF(selectedUserName==null,true,false)}">
                                     <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="RowNum"/>
                                    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Recent Approved Expenses"  id="pageBlockSectionsmAllExp"  columns="1" collapsible="false" >                                  
                                 <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="max-height:85%; overflow-y:scroll" id="main">
                                   <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="pageblock2Exp" >
```

Trying to make the Vertical scollbar work in a 100% correct way.